# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT Error Generated When Redirecting Requests

Tags: node.js, rest, http, express, api-design

I am using the Node.js framework and Express module to write an API wrapper that redirects requests to another server. I can successfully redirect the request to the target server and I receive a valid response containing a JSON payload. However, after the initial request, if I try another request I get the following error.

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

This is a sample of the code I wrote for the HTTP GET Express route:

```
app.get('/companyrecords/:name', function(req, res) {

  const options = {
    protocol: 'http:',
    hostname: 'myhost',
    port: 5001,
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/path/to/resource/?name=name',
    auth: 'username:password',
    headers: {
      Connection: 'close'
    }
  }

  const myAppReq = http.request(options, (myAppRes) =>{
    console.log(`STATUS: ${myAppRes.statusCode}`);
    myAppRes.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
      res.send(chunk);
    });
        myAppRes.on('end', () => {
        res.end('No more data to send.');
    });
  });

  myAppReq.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(`Problem with request: ${err.message}`);
  });

  myAppReq.write('');
  myAppReq.end();
});
```

Not sure why I am getting this error since I am calling the req.write() method so that the request's headers are sent. When looking at the error stack trace it appears the error occurs when I call the res.send() method inside the callback to the 'data' event. Perhaps I'm not understanding the flow of execution among the request or the sequence in which the events are being emitted. Any guidance/information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be sending the response inside `data` event callback because response will be sent when you will receive the first chunk of data. What you should do is to write the `chunk` to response stream and send response inside `end` event callback:

```
const myAppReq = http.request(options, (myAppRes) =>{
    myAppRes.on('data', (chunk) => {
      res.write(chunk);
    });
    myAppRes.on('end', () => {
      res.end();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it now. I found that the res object in Express is "just an enhanced version of Node's own response object" [link] http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res. I was using res.send() because I wasn't aware it had a write method. I've noticed that Express objects inherit most of their properties and methods from Node's own HTTP module. One thing I wasn't understanding was how the sequence of events emitted by the request and response objects determine when to write data to the response stream. Anyways, I changed my code to what you suggested and it works great. Thanks!